# Kal Linux command line is messed up

Tags: linux, command-line, zsh, kali-linux

I'm using Kali Linux live booting off a USB flash drive and for some reason my command line looks like this:

[image: Command line image]

I've looked on Google and can't find a way to get a regular straight command line. I tried `apt-get --purge remove zsh` but that didn't work. I'm sure it's a simple fix I'm just not used to Linux.

Comment: Have you trued simply typing in `exit` and hitting “Return/Enter?” Seems like you are in a sub shell.

Answer (score 1):

It's not "messed up", just customized. This is normal, intended behavior in new Kali versions.

The command prompt can be customized by editing the `$PS1` environment variable. Put your changes in `.zshrc` to make them persistent, otherwise they will apply per terminal only.

Alternatively change the shell to bash: either temporarily by simply typing `bash`, or permanently using the `chsh` command.